# Custom Formating of Number for Phone and Account Number

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I would like to seek advice how or what to use in formatting this two number that will be coming from `JSON` File.

```
var firstnumber = 09151234567
var secondnumber = 1075736332
```

First number should be shown as `"0915 123 4567"`

Second number should be show as `"1075 7363 32"`

i tried looking for codes but what i only see are formatted only with specific country. I would be implementing this in a vuejs

Comment: `First number should be shown as` ...  `Second number should be show as` ... why? note, `var firstnumber = 09151234567` will make the first number `9151234567` - perhaps that's why *your code* doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since leading zero in a Number in javascript is ignored, you'll need to work with strings

```js
var firstnumber = '09151234567';
var secondnumber = '1075736332';
function modify(n) {
  var re1 = /^(\d{4})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/;
  var re2 = /^(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d\d)$/;
  var m = n.match(n.length == 11 ? re1 : re2);
  return m && m.slice(1).join(' ')
}
console.log(modify(firstnumber))
console.log(modify(secondnumber))
```